# Sendto() function giving errors . How to debug them?

Tags: c++

```
    /*
** talker.c -- a datagram "client" demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std ;
#define SERVERPORT "3200775" // the port users will be connecting to

int main()
{ string s;

ifstream f1 ("queries1.txt");
if (f1.is_open()) 

{
while (!f1.eof()) 
{
getline(f1,s);
cout<<s<<endl;
        }

}
    int sockfd;
    //char ch [] = "hello";

struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
int rv;
int numbytes;

// if (argc != 3) {
// fprintf(stderr,"usage: talker hostname message\n");
// exit(1);
//}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

if ((rv = getaddrinfo("nunki.usc.edu", SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
return 1;
}

// loop through all the results and make a socket
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) 
{
if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) 
{
perror("talker: socket");
continue;
}

break;
}

if (p == NULL) 
{
fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to bind socket\n");
return 2;
}

//if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd,ch, strlen(ch), 0,
// p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
//perror("talker: sendto");
//exit(1);

//for (f=0 ;f<15; f++ )
 //   {

    char* mess = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    sprintf(mess,s);
         if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd,mess, s.length(), 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) 
{ cout<<s; 
  perror("talker: sendto");
  exit(1);

} 
printf("talker: sent %d bytes to \n", numbytes);
cout<<endl;
//}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

//printf("talker: sent %d bytes to \n", numbytes);

close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the sloppy way of coding .  I am getting errors in this . How do i debug it ?

The errors are these

```
test.cpp:84: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’
test.cpp:85: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)’
```

Comment: Whoa. That indentation (or is it neglect thereof?) really hurts the eye.

Comment: Unless you tell us exactly what errors you are getting it's doubtful we can help you.

Comment: Learn to indent the code properly. A lot of issues will get solved. I added a closing brace while indenting your code.

Comment: sorry was in a bit of a hurry . I have included the errors now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First corrections to your code:

```
char* mess = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
sprintf(mess,s);
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd,mess, s.length(), 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) 
    // ...
```

1. There's no need to dynamically allocated such a little buffer, whose size is predictable at compile-time.
2. `s` is a `string` object, not a pointer to `char*`.
3. Even if it was a pointer to `char*`: it's very unsuitable to use `sprintf`, since the source string may contain format codes ('%'). Imagine what happens if it contains '%s'.
4. How do you know the string won't be longer than 19 characters? You **can't** know this at compile time.
5. Anyway, `sprintf` should be used if you want to do the string formatting. There's no need to use it if you just need the string as-is.

This shame list can be continued. Simply speaking you should rewrite it this way:

```
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, (char*) s.c_str(), s.length(), 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) 
    // ...
```

Regarding your specific problem. If we assume the actual problem is not from the mentioned list - there's usually complementary sockets functions that can give you the reach error information.

For instance, on Windows there's a `WSAGetLastError` function that can be used immediately after you get the error.

Comment: The OP has perfectly portable (even if broken) code, using standard POSIX functions. Why involve something Windows-specific here, when there are the far more portable alternatives of strerror(), perror() etc?

Answer (score 0):

Change those lines to:

```
 char *mess = (char *)malloc (20 * sizeof (char));
 sprintf(mess, s.c_str());
```

The first one needs an explicit cast, and in the second line you have to explicitly produce a C-style string from a C++ string.

EDIT:

Keep in mind that the c_str() method of std::string only provides a pointer to an internal structure of the object. If you destroy the string, that pointer is no longer valid, so take care to use strdup() or similar if necessary.

EDIT2:

If you really want to do it properly, you should really use strdup() instead of sprintf():

```
mess = strdup(s.c_str());
```

Don't forget to free() the mess pointer when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your port is way out of range. Port numbers for TCP and UDP are 16-bit integers, i.e. the max is 65535.